# Android app to remind me when I get back to my current location, or to a saved waypoint

Tags: navigation

Immediate use case--there's a piece of trash beside the trail not too far in from the trailhead.  I want to pick it up on the way back, I do not want to lug it multiple miles into the backcountry.  Unfortunately, while it's clearly visible to an outbound hiker I have yet to find it on the way back.

Secondary use case--marking non-obvious trail features.  Stuff like GaiaGPS will let me drop waypoints, but I'm after something that will notify me as I'm approaching.

Yes, this will obviously keep the GPS powered up--but it's going to be powered up anyway.  Fully local operation is mandatory as service out there is patchy at best.

Comment: AFAIR eg OsmAnd "throws a notification" on stored favorites (flags) when you pass them (I remember having noticed that on a trip) when running in foreground (eg for navigation). Other apps to look at would be [Location Memos](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationmemos) or even better [Location Alerts & Reminders](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationalert) (links go to my listings), which would be specialized for your use cases. Not using any of those, I cannot name the best matching candidate.

Comment: @Izzy That looks like a very useful site!

Comment: Thanks! Enjoy it! It's also constantly updated (existing entries update themselves automatically, new ones are permanently added whenever I find useful stuff). // PS: when you find something fitting your needs, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)